# Why use single Newton-Raphson step in Gradient Boosting Machine

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, boosting

In the following paper:

> Greedy Function Approximation: A Gradient Boosting Machine
>   https://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf

on page 9 it tries to find the optimal step size $\gamma$ on equation (23) by approximating by a single Newton-Raphson step.

Why a single step and not more steps in order to get closer to the minimum?

Comment: More steps are accurate for finding the exact step size, decreasing the train loss, but not necessarily the test loss. So one step only can be thought of a way of regularization?